# Error message (sig_complete event failed) when running an executable on Cygwin Bash Shell

Tags: cygwin, fortran, signals

I am running an executable in Cygwin Bash Shell.  The executable is compiled Fortran code; I have placed a Fortran statement `PRINT *, "done"` at the end of my code (just before the final line of code, `END PROGRAM aug3`, where `aug3` is the name of my program.  The code appears to compile fine and I get a resulting executable, *a.exe*.  In Cygwin, if I execute *a.exe* using the command while in the folder:

```
$ ./a
done
```

...which suggests (but does not prove) that my program is finished running, since the Fortran statement `PRINT *, "done"` is the second-to-last line in my Fortran code, before `END PROGRAM aug3`.  But, after printing `done`, Cygwin just sits--I do not get another command prompt, and if I try to type something, the text does not appear.  After about a minute, I get the following error message (and after that I finally get another command prompt):

> 12 [main] a 592 sig_send: wait for sig_complete event failed, signal 6, rc
>   258, Win32 error 0
>   Aborted

Do you know what this error message means?  Does it likely refer to a problem in my Fortran code (in which case I should ask this question on a Fortran message board), or is it likely a problem with my Cygwin Bash?  When I search around on the internet, the [posts that I see](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2000-09/msg00519.html) seem to suggest that "wait for sig_complete event failed" evidences a problem with Cygwin.

Do you have any suggestions of how I can diagnose and fix my error message?

Comment: Is the code compiled *for* cygwin, or was it compiled for another platform and you're just trying to run it under cygwin?

Comment: This looks more like a question about Cygwin as a Windows application than about Cygwin as a unix implementation. So I think it would fare better on [su].

Comment: Thanks. It was compiled *for* Cygwin, using the gfortran compiler installed through Cygwin's setup.

Comment: @Gilles you don't think that it'd be better on SO? seems to me like it's possibly a programming error. SU tends not to be the right place for diagnosing programming issues.

Comment: @xenoterracide Oh, right, I hadn't noticed “my code”. So this is an SO question, except that they'll complain that the code isn't shown. Andrew: you need to shrink your program to a small example that exhibits the problem, then post your code, on [so]. If you don't manage to reproduce the problem with a small program, ask for debugging advice, again on [so].

Comment: @Gilles OK, that sounds good, thank you.  I have been trying for the last hour to shrink my program down to a small example with the same problem, but I am not yet able to reproduce the problem.  My entire code is about two pages--still fairly long, but I guess not totally unreasonable to ask for debugging advice (after I try some more to shrink my code).  Thanks for your help, everyone.

Comment: You'll get more useful'eyes' on your question if add a tag for fortan and maybe gcc. Good luck.

Comment: Andrew: I don't know how long your pages are, but posting 50 lines is not out of the question. @shellter As you can see, this is a migrated post, it's common that they have tags that don't correspond well with the target site. When you see one, please do retag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so sorry... I've found my mistake, and my program is working now.  In my Fortran code, I was inadvertently referencing an array element that was out of bounds, although I never got an array index out of bounds error message.  Fixing this bug means that my program now not only compiles fine, but also runs fine.  Thank you for all your time and for all your patience.  Sorry to waste your time on "my bad."  This thread is resolved.